# gcda files are not generated while running the functional test cases on the instrumented image

Tags: c, instrumentation, gcov

I am trying to generate the coverage for C files (Yocto project).

So, I have added gcov flags **"-g -O0 --coverage"** in the Makefile.am of most of the available modules.

It generated ".gcno" files during the compilation of each module with coverage flags.

I have generated an image from all these modules and loaded it in the test device and ran functional test cases.

I am able to find the path of the "gcda" files using strings command from the process that is running the test device.

So I have used gdb mode to flush the coverage using the "__gcov_flush" command after attaching the process id to gdb.

This throws an error "No symbol __gcov_flush in current context". Please suggest me what may be the cause for this error.

Comment: Not a makefile question. Removed incorrect tag.

Comment: Please have a look at your build log (enable verbose mode if you don't see any commands) and then add an example compiler command line, i.e. from a module where you expect `--coverage` to be used, and a linker command to your question text. For coverage to work you'll need it to be enabled in the compilation **and** linking command lines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan Becker.

Actually I am building a yocto image so using bitbake to compile the code. So there is no make command line to add debug mode.

The compilation generated .gcno successfully for a module. While running the functional test cases for the module, .gcda files are not generated.

Comment: Are you trying to get coverage for Linux Kernel or driver module?

Comment: Yes Ameya. We are trying to get the coverage for Yocto modules (both kernel and driver)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments it is not directly possible to just build the Linux Kernel with the Coverage Compiler flags and assume to get meaningful coverage metrics.

The Code Coverage metrics actually require some file systems to be available to write the run-time coverage data(i.e. *.gcda files).

If you want to enable Code Coverage for Linux Kernel [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/dev-tools/gcov.html) is a documentation on how to go about enabling the support using a GCOV virtual filesystem to collect coverage metrics.

Also, assuming you are cross compiling for a different architecture then probably you will have to use a cross-gcov tool to collect the coverage metrics, after you have captured the *.gcno files after execution.